# Simulate read_timeout with Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I need to test that my PHP script is correctly handling the read_timeout option in my Guzzle requests. So I wrote 2 PHP scripts, one calling the other using Guzzle and I want to achieve the timeout this way. But from some reason I am not getting the timeout. The doc states that the timeout only works when stream is set to true and when using the CurlHandler but both I have verified. May be I am not doing the server part well so that really no data is sent? Or why does the timeout not work? I had several versions of the scripts, now I use this one.
Client:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

$client = new Client(["read_timeout"=> 2, "stream" => true]);

try {
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8002/server_test.php', [
        'stream' => true,
        'read_timeout' => 2  // Just the read timeout
    ]);

    $body = $response->getBody();

    while (!$body->eof()) {
        echo $body->read(1024);
    }

} catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Server side:

```
<?php

// Stream the response
$stream = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$start_time = time();

// Stream data with delay
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    fwrite($stream, "Data chunk $i\n");
    sleep(6); 
}

$data = "\nStart time: $start_time\nEnd time: " . time();
fwrite($stream, $data);
fclose($stream);
?>
```

The client script is calling the server script and should get the timeout because the server script waits for 6 seconds between sending the chunks. Yet no timeout happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be **no streaming support** for the `CurlHandler` and there's no Curl option for `read timeout` (but for `timeout` and `connect timeout`). You might want to use the `timeout` option if you don't necessarily need the timeout to not start before a connection has been established.

```
$client = new Client();
$handler = new CurlHandler();
$response = $client->request('GET', '/lengthy.php', [
    'timeout' => 5,
    'handler' => $handler
]);
```

will be working and throwing a `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException` (with 0 bytes received) when timing out.

If you absolutely need the timeout to be a `read timeout` (excluding the connection time) you could still use:

```
$client = new Client();
$handler = new StreamHandler();
$response = $client->request('GET', '/lengthy.php', [
    'read_timeout' => 5,
    'handler' => $handler
]);
```

which will throw a `RuntimeException` when timing out. But be aware, that the timeout won't start before the first byte has been transmitted. I had to use `flush()` in my `lengthy.php` explicitly for that to happen.

As of now I've found no way to access the data received before the timeout occurred.

Using async requests (and monitor them) might be another option to tackle the timeout problem.

Comment: I see. I cannot immediately verify that the answer is correct but if it is true, it answers my question. 
This means that the Guzzle docs about read_timeout is completely wrong. Also it means that read_timeout in Guzzle is not a mechanism that one could use to detect that the server does not/stopped sending the data. I guess I will need to implement a streamed receiving of the data somehow and detect myself that there were no data sent for a longer time.

Comment: For `'stream' => true` the documentation states `Streaming response support must be implemented by the HTTP handler used by a client.`. The cURL handler hasn't. But there is an open feature request, which you might want to support: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/3115

Comment: So you **can** use `read_timeout` with Guzzle in general, but not when using the cURL handler.

Comment: You say in your answer: "the timeout won't start before the first byte has been transmitted". So that means that the timeout does not work propely even with the streaming handler, doesn't it? In every case I need to detect the timeout even in this case as a read timeout. So that is not doable whatever handler I use and that Guzzle option is unusable as a full working read timeout.

Comment: I agree, it should timeout no matter whether a byte has been transmitted or not.